# getting Error in gtkmm code

Tags: c++, gtkmm

The error is very unusual for me..
No file name..
Not a correct line number
Error is :
building menus failed: Error on line 1 char 19: Odd character '’', expected an open quote mark after the equals sign when giving value for attribute 'action' of

File: examplewindow.h

```
#ifndef GTKMM_EXAMPLEWINDOW_H
#define GTKMM_EXAMPLEWINDOW_H
#include <gtkmm.h>
class ExampleWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
ExampleWindow();
virtual ~ExampleWindow();
protected:
//Signal handlers:
virtual void on_menu_file_new_generic();
virtual void on_menu_file_quit();
virtual void on_menu_others();
virtual void on_menu_choices_one();
virtual void on_menu_choices_two();
//Child widgets:
Gtk::VBox m_Box;
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::UIManager> m_refUIManager;
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::ActionGroup> m_refActionGroup;
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::RadioAction> m_refChoiceOne, m_refChoiceTwo;
};
#endif //GTKMM_EXAMPLEWINDOW_H
```

File: main.cc

```
#include <gtkmm/main.h>
#include "examplewindow.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
Gtk::Main kit(argc, argv);
ExampleWindow window;
//Shows the window and returns when it is closed.
Gtk::Main::run(window);
return 0;
}
```

File: examplewindow.cc

```
#include "examplewindow.h"
#include <gtkmm/stock.h>
#include <iostream>
ExampleWindow::ExampleWindow()
{
set_title("main menu example");
set_default_size(200, 200);
add(m_Box); // put a MenuBar at the top of the box and other stuff below it.
//Create actions for menus and toolbars:
m_refActionGroup = Gtk::ActionGroup::create();
//File|New sub menu:
m_refActionGroup->add(Gtk::Action::create("FileNewStandard",
G    tk::Stock::NEW, "_New", "Create a new file"),
sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ExampleWindow::on_menu_file_new_generic));
m_refActionGroup->add(Gtk::Action::create("FileNewFoo",
Gtk::Stock::NEW, "New Foo", "Create a new foo"),
sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ExampleWindow::on_menu_file_new_generic));
m_refActionGroup->add(Gtk::Action::create("FileNewGoo",
Gtk::Stock::NEW, "_New Goo", "Create a new goo"),
sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ExampleWindow::on_menu_file_new_generic));
//File menu:
m_refActionGroup->add(Gtk::Action::create("FileMenu", "File"));
//Sub-menu.
m_refActionGroup->add(Gtk::Action::create("FileNew", Gtk::Stock::NEW));
m_refActionGroup->add(Gtk::Action::create("FileQuit", Gtk::Stock::QUIT),
sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ExampleWindow::on_menu_file_quit));
//Edit menu:
m_refActionGroup->add(Gtk::Action::create("EditMenu", "Edit"));
m_refActionGroup->add(Gtk::Action::create("EditCopy", Gtk::Stock::COPY),
sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ExampleWindow::on_menu_others));
m_refActionGroup->add(Gtk::Action::create("EditPaste", Gtk::Stock::PASTE),
sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ExampleWindow::on_menu_others));
m_refActionGroup->add(Gtk::Action::create("EditSomething", "Something"),
Gtk::AccelKey("<control><alt>S"),
sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ExampleWindow::on_menu_others));
//Choices menu, to demonstrate Radio items
m_refActionGroup->add( Gtk::Action::create("ChoicesMenu", "Choices") );
Gtk::RadioAction::Group group_userlevel;
m_refChoiceOne = Gtk::RadioAction::create(group_userlevel, "ChoiceOne", "One");
m_refActionGroup->add(m_refChoiceOne,
sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ExampleWindow::on_menu_choices_one) );
m_refChoiceTwo = Gtk::RadioAction::create(group_userlevel, "ChoiceTwo", "Two");
m_refActionGroup->add(m_refChoiceTwo,
sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ExampleWindow::on_menu_choices_two) );
//Help menu:
m_refActionGroup->add( Gtk::Action::create("HelpMenu", "Help") );
m_refActionGroup->add( Gtk::Action::create("HelpAbout", Gtk::Stock::HELP),
sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ExampleWindow::on_menu_others) );
m_refUIManager = Gtk::UIManager::create();
m_refUIManager->insert_action_group(m_refActionGroup);
add_accel_group(m_refUIManager->get_accel_group());
//Layout the actions in a menubar and toolbar:
Glib::ustring ui_info =
"<ui>"
" <menubar name=’MenuBar’>"
"
<menu action=’FileMenu’>"
"
<menu action=’FileNew’>"
"
<menuitem action=’FileNewStandard’/>"
"
<menuitem action=’FileNewFoo’/>"
"
<menuitem action=’FileNewGoo’/>"
"
</menu>"
"
<separator/>"
"
<menuitem action=’FileQuit’/>"
"
</menu>"
"
<menu action=’EditMenu’>"
"
<menuitem action=’EditCopy’/>"
"
<menuitem action=’EditPaste’/>"
"
<menuitem action=’EditSomething’/>"
"
</menu>"
"
<menu action=’ChoicesMenu’>"
"
<menuitem action=’ChoiceOne’/>"
"
<menuitem action=’ChoiceTwo’/>"
"
</menu>"
"
<menu action=’HelpMenu’>"
"
<menuitem action=’HelpAbout’/>"
"
</menu>"
" </menubar>"
" <toolbar name=’ToolBar’>"
"
<toolitem action=’FileNewStandard’/>"
"
<toolitem action=’FileQuit’/>"
" </toolbar>"
"</ui>";
#ifdef GLIBMM_EXCEPTIONS_ENABLED
try
{
m_refUIManager->add_ui_from_string(ui_info);
}
catch(const Glib::Error& ex)
{
std::cerr << "building menus failed: " << ex.what();
}
#else
std::auto_ptr<Glib::Error> ex;
m_refUIManager->add_ui_from_string(ui_info, ex);
if(ex.get())
{
std::cerr << "building menus failed: " << ex->what();
}
#endif //GLIBMM_EXCEPTIONS_ENABLED
//Get the menubar and toolbar widgets, and add them to a container widget:
Gtk::Widget* pMenubar = m_refUIManager->get_widget("/MenuBar");
if(pMenubar)
m_Box.pack_start(*pMenubar, Gtk::PACK_SHRINK);
Gtk::Widget* pToolbar = m_refUIManager->get_widget("/ToolBar") ;
if(pToolbar)
m_Box.pack_start(*pToolbar, Gtk::PACK_SHRINK);
show_all_children();
}
ExampleWindow::~ExampleWindow()
{
}
void ExampleWindow::on_menu_file_quit()
{
hide(); //Closes the main window to stop the Gtk::Main::run().
}
void ExampleWindow::on_menu_file_new_generic()
{
std::cout << "A File|New menu item was selected." << std::endl;
}
void ExampleWindow::on_menu_others()
{
std::cout << "A menu item was selected." << std::endl;
}
void ExampleWindow::on_menu_choices_one()
{
Glib::ustring message;
if(m_refChoiceOne->get_active())
message = "Choice 1 was selected.";
else
message = "Choice 1 was deselected";
std::cout << message << std::endl;
}
void ExampleWindow::on_menu_choices_two()
{
Glib::ustring message;
if(m_refChoiceTwo->get_active())
message = "Choice 2 was selected.";
else
message = "Choice 2 was deselected";
std::cout << message << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're using the wrong quote in your xml string. Try `'` not `’`